# How to automatically add a profile to a ManyToManyField?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have this model of a course

```
class Minicursos(models.Model):
     nome_minicurso = models.CharField(max_length=150)

     resumo = models.TextField(max_length=500, default = "")
     descricao = models.TextField(max_length=500, default = "")

     imagem_minicurso = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery", height_field=None, 
     width_field=None, max_length=None, default = "")
     video_explicativo = models.FileField(upload_to="video/%y", default="",)

     carga_horaria = models.IntegerField()

     alunos = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, 'Alunos')
```

my html is like this

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form id="ingressar-form" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <a href="/minicurso/{{minicurso.id}}/aulas.html"><button id="ingressar" type="submit" value="Create">INGRESSAR</button></a>
        </form>
{% else %}
    <strong><p>Para ingressar no minicurso faça <a href="/login">Login</a> ou <a href="/register">Registre-se</a>.</p></strong>
{% endif %}
```

I wish that when the user clicks on 'ingressar' his profile, it will be added to the field students (alunos)

i tried it

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    
    aluno = Minicursos.alunos.add(User)
    aluno.save()
```

but I get this error

aluno = Minicursos.alunos.add(User)
AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'

Someone can help me please!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only add an object to an instance of a model, not to the class object. So you first need to create an instance of `Minicursos`.

You can check the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for a detailed explanation.